# Bootstrap 3 Tooltip displaying raw HTML instead of HTML formatted text

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, coffeescript

I'm attempting to use a Bootstrap 3 tooltip to display some custom HTML-formatted text. I've wrapped the tooltip in an Ember component for re-use later.

As you can see below, I'm setting the data-html attribute to true, and setting the title to some arbitrary HTML formatted text, but when I hover to trigger the tooltip, it displays the raw HTML string instead.

Tooltip component:

```
App.ToolTipComponent = Ember.Component.extend
  text:       undefined
  placement:  undefined
  html:       undefined
  htmlText:   undefined

  afterRenderEvent: ->
    childElem = @$(":first-child")
    childElem.attr('data-toggle', 'tooltip')
    childElem.attr('data-trigger', 'hover')
    childElem.attr('data-placement', @get('placement'))

    childElem.attr('data-html', 'true')
    childElem.attr('title', '<b>Test Data</b>')

    childElem.tooltip()
```

This is what the output looks like on the application. The tooltip is triggered when hovering over 'testCampaign', and as you can see, only displays raw HTML.

[image: Output image]

And here's the inspection from Chrome's development tools. In comparing with the fiddle with the same functionality [here](http://jsfiddle.net/56arN/), I can't see what needs to be changed.

```
<div data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="<b>Test Data</b>">
  <script id="metamorph-132-start" type="text/x-placeholder" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="<b>Test Data</b>"></script>
  "testCampaign"
  <script id="metamorph-132-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script></div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle you have the attribute **data-title** populated.

> data-title="< table>< tr>< td style='color:red;'>complex&nbsp ;< /td>< td>HTML< /td>< /tr>< /table>">

In your provided example you have only populated the **title** attribute:

> title="**Test Data**"

Also in your provided example you have opened the script tag, but not closed it

```
<div data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="<b>Test Data</b>">
  <script id="metamorph-856-start" type="text/x-placeholder" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="<b>Test Data</b>">
  testCampaign
</div>
```

Comment: The fiddle was the example I was drawing on to come up with this implementation. When I try to populate the data-title attribute, the tooltip does not display at all.

Thanks for finding that script typo. I was trying to cut out non-related fields and must have gone one character too far. I'll update that now.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new fork of the Fiddle you mentioned and implemented your Component:
https://jsfiddle.net/hwzbxuwL/4/

I've updated `afterRenderEvent` to `didInsertElement` (this is probably more to match the API changes from Ember updates since your post).

```
App.ToolTipComponent = Ember.Component.extend
    text:       undefined
    placement:  undefined
    html:       undefined
    htmlText:   undefined
    didInsertElement: ->
      childElem = @$(":first-child")
      childElem.attr('data-toggle', 'tooltip')
      childElem.attr('data-trigger', 'hover')
      childElem.attr('data-placement', @get('placement'))

      childElem.attr('data-html', 'true')
      childElem.attr('title', '<b><i>Test Data</i></b>')

      childElem.tooltip()
```

I've also added the latest (as of this posting) Ember v1.11.1 and some other deps needed to run it in jsfiddle.

If you're still having issues with the component, can you share more details.